# Google Search Console diplaying my URLs are indexed but it is not showing in search result by parameter site: search

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, web-crawlers, canonical-url

Can anyone provide the solution about this issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: GSC is not saying that it is indexed.  It says it's available.  Have you pressed **Request Indexing**?

Comment: `site:` search is not a valid way to test if something is indexed.  Google doesn't show all indexed pages from a `site:` search.